# Thread safety MPI communication

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mpi, mutex

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836560/thread-safety-of-mpi-send-using-threads-created-with-stdasync) I recently learned, that one has to be very careful using MPI with several threads communicating. Since the implementation I use doesn't support `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`, I just wrapped every `MPI::COMM_WORLD` call with a `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`.

My question now: Is this overkill? To be specific: Can I `Send` at the exact time I `Recv`?

I tried it with two `std::mutex`, one for sending, one for receiving. On my testing machine, I had several test runs without an error, but that isn't a guarantee, it might be just coincidence..

Addition: Now - with hundreds of test runs - there actually occured one lousy segmentation fault, but I'm not 100% sure about if this due to simultaneous send/recv.

Comment: did you try this across a network? on a test machine locally it might behave different, message send/recv times aren't deterministic and neither is the lock/unlock of the mutex

Comment: @pyCthon I did this only locally, but it seems that even that fails. Different communicators aren't the solution either, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Which MPI threading mode are you using?  Using a mutex is not sufficient unless you are using `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`, in which case you will need to use a single mutex around all MPI calls.  That does serialize them, as you are seeing.  If you are not using `MPI_Init_thread` with `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED` (i.e., you are using `MPI_Init` or some lower thread setting), even using a mutex is not enough; see the MPI standard for the exact restrictions.  If you are using `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`, the rule is that you cannot enter MPI calls from multiple threads at the same time, regardless of whether they are the same operation or different.

Comment: I don't understand why `std::mutex` and `MPI_Init` shouldn't be enough. This effectively serializes the calls to MPI communication, so it can't be any different from single thread usage. Saying differently would mean that it is not safe to use `MPI_Init` ever. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: It is not safe to use plain `MPI_Init` if your program uses threads at all (even if it does not use MPI from the other threads).

Comment: See section 12.4.3 (top of page 486) of the MPI 3.0 standard (http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf) for the rules for different thread levels.