# How accelerate MPI-calls?

Tags: mpi, openmp, mpich

I try to accelerate simple MPI-programm with OpenMP. I use MPICH2 and 4-core Intel processor. I have simple code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int size, rank, provided;
    const int root = 0;

    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int cubeCount = StrToDouble(argv[1]);
    int matrixSize = *StrToDouble(argv[2]);
    WorkNode node(rank, size, cubeCount, matrixSize);
    time_t t0 = time(0);
    node.work();
    time_t t1 = time(0);
    time_t total = t1 - t0;
```

Class WorkNode also very simple, contains only array of Cube and method work.

```
class Cube {
public:
    Cube(int matrixSize);
    double *matrix;
    int matrixSize;
}

Cube::Cube(int matrixSize) {
    matrix = new double[matrixSize];
    this->matrixSize = matrixSize;
}
```

Finally method work:

```
// double *inBuffer = new double[cubes[0]->matrixSize];
MPI_Status status;
for (int i = 0; i < processorCount; i++) {
    int nodeToSend = this->id + i;
    int nodeRecv = this->id - i;

    if (nodeToSend >= processorCount) {
        nodeToSend -= processorCount;
    }
    if (nodeRecv < 0) {
        nodeRecv += processorCount;
    }
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < cubeCount; i++) {
        Cube *cube = cubes[i];
        if (nodeToSend != this->id) {
            MPI_Bsend(cube->matrix, cube->matrixSize, MPI_DOUBLE, nodeToSend, _MY_MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        if (nodeRecv != this->id) {
            double *inBuffer = new double[cubes[0]->matrixSize];
            MPI_Recv(inBuffer, cube->matrixSize, MPI_DOUBLE, nodeRecv, _MY_MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            delete inBuffer;
        }
    }
}
//delete inBuffer
```

Unfortunately, openMP does not accelerate the program (even if the number of MPI processes = 2), and sometimes even slows down. Can I somehow accelerate MPI calls?

Comment: Is your MPI implementation built with thread safety enabled?  The way you're using MPI inside of OpenMP makes me think you'd need that, but it may not be the default.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14837206/4323 .

Comment: Yes, provided == MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE

Comment: Honestly it seems slightly odd to use multithreading and MPI in the same program like this.  If I were you I'd simply consider changing to a multi-process model and using MPI that way, without multiple threads.