# Is it safe to use MPI_Send and MPI_Recv simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mpi

Simplifying, in my program every MPI process has two threads. First thread receives all messages via *MPI_Recv* and second thread sends messages via *MPI_Send*, so of course these two operations can occur simultaneously.
Is it considered as safe? Can this cause deadlock or other unwanted situations?

Comment: Multi-threaded code is hard, even for smart people.  Yes, there can be deadlocks and unwanted situations.

Comment: Punch `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` into your favorite search engine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MPI, but it looks like there's a set of implementations for it, and the answer to your question will depend on which one you're using. I'm guessing Boost's wrapper? Anyway a quick search and a skim of the answer reveals this question which may be a duplicate (I don't know enough about the context to be sure): http://stackoverflow.com/q/14836560/1180785