# Is it safe to call MPI_Init from different thread?

Tags: c++, mpi

Is it safe to call `MPI_Init` from a `std::thread`?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::thread mpi_thread([...](){
        MPI_Init(...);

       // All MPI calls are done by this thread.

        MPI_Finalize();
    });

    // The main thread is doing different stuff

    mpi_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that but I wonder what's the purpose of this.

Comment: You probably also want to use [Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/mpi.html) for a nicer interface.

Comment: I am for the moment, but `Boost.MPI` comes with its own set of problems. Many times you have to fall back to the MPI documentation to guess, what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MPI standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) has a section about *MPI and Threads*. One important part is:

> Initialization and Completion The call to `MPI_FINALIZE` should occur on the same thread that initialized MPI. We call this thread the **main thread**. The call should occur only after
>   all process threads have completed their MPI calls, and have no pending communications or I/O operations.

Your code does fulfill this requirement.

MPI knows several levels of thread support. Your code requires:

> **`MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`** The process may be multi-threaded, but the application must ensure that only the main thread makes MPI calls.

For good measure, you should call the following instead of `MPI_Init`:

```
int provided;
MPI_Init_thread(NULL, NULL, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided);
if (provided < MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED)
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, -1);
```

A MPI library that is not thread compliant must return `provided == MPI_THREAD_SINGLE` indicating you won't be able to use this implementation correctly with your code.

In practice, you should be fine with the common implementations. For more information about the different levels of thread support, see 12.4.3 in the MPI standard. With the higher levels of thread support, your mileage may vary depending on the implementation you chose.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats great detail thx for the ref to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Okay there are two issues here

1) Is the code presented in the question "safe"

Yes, the code shown here is 100% safe because the MPI computation happens on a single thread. If something is "going wrong" we need a reproducible example that includes the compiler and some information about the cluster. There is a chance its due to a vendor specific configuration issue, many years ago vendors would "bless" the main thread for MPI.

2) Is MPI thread safe? AKA can you call `MPI_RECV` on a second thread?

This is harder question that is discussed here: [thread safety of MPI send using threads created with std::async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836560/thread-safety-of-mpi-send-using-threads-created-with-stdasync)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am aware, that MPI in general is not thread safe (had to learn this the hard way).

Comment: I would even say that part (2) of your answer is ill-advised.  Such a situation more or less guarantees a deadlock.

Comment: @HenriMenke Which part?  I wouldn't recommend combining threading libraries (aka use pthreads/std:: for node local communication but MPI between nodes), if not simply for code complexity. Although some research groups with too many resources do this.